# confusion between auth and access_token parameters

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am using https://web.postman.co to test my Access Rules in firebase realtime database, so i am successfully authenticating user and generating an idToken. after that i am inserting a simple json data using POST request.

so when i use https://********.firebaseio.com/messages.json?***auth=idToken*** i get 200 OK response header and i get the json response as the body indicating the key of the inserted data,but when posting using https://********.firebaseio.com/messages.json?***access_token=idToken*** i get 401 unauthorised status and as response body i get
{
"error": "Unauthorized request."
}
i am reading the docs here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?hl=uk#authenticate_with_an_access_token

and here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database?hl=uk#section-param-auth

**and can't figure out when to use auth and access_token or what is the difference?**

**here is the data base rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages":{
        ".indexOn":"date_captured",
        ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do your database rues look like? Maybe the action is restricted there?

Comment: it is not the issue since i can successfully retrieve and write data to firebase. yes the read and write actions are restricted in the database rule but the problem is that can successfully push and retrieve data with https://********.firebaseio.com/messages.json?auth=<idToken>but i get { "error": "Unauthorized request." } when using https://********.firebaseio.com/messages.json?<access_token=idToken>  and i just want to understand why.

Comment: do you use te same idToken for both?

Comment: yes of course the same idtoken. but as you can see my question, i am not looking for for solution to a problem since i can push and retrieve data successfully one way or another. rather i am looking for an explanation because i want to have a deep understanding of cloud database ,HTTP ,and java. Thank you anyway for your help. i will just proceed with https://********.firebaseio.com/messages.json?auth=<idToken> since it do the job.